# Search 500000 queries on google custom search per day

Tags: google-api, google-custom-search

I have already read on google custom search, so there is plan that $5 for 1000 queries and upto 10k per day limit, but i want to search 500k per day so what will be solution and what will be charges if possible.

Comment: I have basically the same question. It's a really expensive service and basically kind of limited if you can only do 10K searches per day.

Answer (score 0):

[Pricing](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview#pricing)

> JSON/Atom Custom Search API provides 100 search queries per day for free. If you need more, you may sign up for billing in the API Console. Additional requests cost $5 per 1000 queries, up to 10k queries per day.

The max is 10k requests per day. I suggest your look into reducing the number of queries you need.   *or make more then one project. no idea if that will work*

Comment: Wow, that is so expensive as to be useless for most applications